# Apache OpenSSL httpd-ssl.conf config stops Apache, no error except when httpd-ssl.conf include disabled

Tags: ssl

I followed directions to setup SSL on my custom WAPP stack (Windows/Apach/PHP/PostgreSQL) here...

http://www.tehuber.com/article.php?story=20110315153800545

After back-tracking I discovered when inside the `apache/conf/httpd.conf` file I comment out the include for `apache/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf` the server starts just fine.

For clarification my Apache directory on Windows 7 64 bit (stack is all 64 bit where applicable) is located at...

> C:/MEDIA/INTERNET/WAPP/Apache 2.4.10 x64/

...while my htdocs directory is located at...

> D:/Media/web/

I've gone through the config file manually and haven't been able to track down the issue. I've removed all the comments to post what I have here as there is probably something that sticks out to someone else that isn't for me...

```
Listen 443
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache "shmcb:C:/MEDIA/INTERNET/WAPP/Apache 2.4.10 x64/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
DocumentRoot "D:/Media/web/"
ServerName localhost:443
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ErrorLog "C:/MEDIA/INTERNET/WAPP/Apache 2.4.10 x64/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "C:/MEDIA/INTERNET/WAPP/Apache 2.4.10 x64/logs/access.log"

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "C:/MEDIA/INTERNET/WAPP/Apache 2.4.10 x64/conf/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/MEDIA/INTERNET/WAPP/Apache 2.4.10 x64/conf/server.key"

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "D:/Media/web/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

CustomLog "C:/MEDIA/INTERNET/WAPP/Apache 2.4.10 x64/logs/ssl_request.log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
```

...when I disable the includes the Apache error log spits out the following...

> [core:warn] [pid 4972:tid 472] AH00098: pid file
>   C:/MEDIA/INTERNET/WAPP/Apache 2.4.10 x64/logs/httpd.pid overwritten --
>   Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
>
> [ssl:warn] [pid 4972:tid 472] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not
>   configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
>
> [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4972:tid 472] AH00455: Apache/2.4.10 (Win64)
>   OpenSSL/1.0.1j PHP/5.6.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4972:tid 472] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11
>   Server built: Jul 17 2014 12:58:29
>
> [core:notice] [pid 4972:tid 472] AH00094: Command line:
>   'C:\MEDIA\INTERNET\WAPP\Apache 2.4.10 x64\bin\httpd.exe -d
>   C:/MEDIA/INTERNET/WAPP/Apache 2.4.10 x64'
>
> [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4972:tid 472] AH00418: Parent: Created child
>   process 5828
>
> [ssl:warn] [pid 5828:tid 484] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not
>   configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
>
> [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5828:tid 484] AH00354: Child: Starting 64
>   worker threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented out the following line...

```
#SSLSessionCache "shmcb:C:/MEDIA/INTERNET/WAPP/Apache 2.4.10 x64/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
```

...though I'm not sure *what* effect, if any, this will have. All SSL pages on localhost seem to load just fine now however.